# Apache Camel jetty is not triggering the SSL service

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, jetty

I am triggering the https service with the camel jetty component.But it is not triggering the service.I am using camel jetty 2.14.3 version

Below is the code snippet,

```
<bean id="jetty" 
       class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent">
    <property name="sslSocketConnectorProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="password" value="pwd"/>
            <entry key="keyPassword" value="pwd"/>
            <entry key="keystore" value="test.jks"/>
            <entry key="needClientAuth" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

 <camel:sslContextParameters id="mySslContext">
  <camel:clientParameters>
    <camel:secureSocketProtocols>
        <camel:secureSocketProtocol>TLSv1.0</camel:secureSocketProtocol>
            </camel:secureSocketProtocols>
        </camel:clientParameters>
```

URL Hitting,
https://test.com/services?sslContextParametersRef=mySslContext&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&httpClient.soTimeout=30000" />

when i am hitting this i am getting the timeout and it is not sending the message to the service.I increased the timeout also still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use HTTP/HTTP4 component. Jetty as a producer is deprecated
[Camel Jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html)